# PHP Form Login - Send Error Message

Tags: php, authentication

I have this line of code and I am trying to send an error message if the username password combination don't match, the thing is the message displays when I access the page, even before i enter a username and password. how do I make the message appear ONLY after login failed?
Thanks!!

```
<?php
$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];

if(($user == "someusername") && ($pass == "somepassword"))
{
        include("../securedfile.php");
}
else{    
  $message = "Invalid User/Password - Please Try Again";
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
   }   

    if(isset ($_POST))

    {?>

            <div class="secure">
            <form method="POST" action="secure.php">
            username:<input class="user" type="text" name="user"></input><br/><br/>
           password:<input class="pass" type="password" name="pass"></input><br/><br/>


            <button class="submit" type="submit" name="submit">SUBMIT</span></button>
            </form>
            </div>
    <?}
    }    
?>
```

Comment: I have no idea how any of your code is working, you have a `<?` instead of a `<?php`, but one thing that you want to do is put the `$username = 'asd' and $password = 'asd'` inside of a `if (isset($_POST))` statement, so try moving the first 2 lines into the if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the parenthesis problem with the 'else', then the form is calling secure.php instead of calling itself, there's no isset...The rewritten code below would be a better way of doing it. And have checked it, it works. (The name of this whole file - new.php)

```
<div class="secure">
        <form method="POST" action="new.php">
        username:<input class="user" type="text" name="user"></input><br/><br/>
        password:<input class="pass" type="password" name="pass"></input><br/><br/>


        <button class="submit" type="submit" name="submit">SUBMIT</span></button>
        </form>
</div>

<?php  
// checking the user
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

  $user = $_POST['user'];
  $pass = $_POST['pass'];

if($user == "someusername" && $pass == "somepassword")
  {
    include("../securedfile.php");
  }

else
 {
 $message = "Invalid User/Password - Please Try Again";
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
 }
}  
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works! Now i need to hide the form, when "securedfile.php" is included.

Comment: I just added `<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('target').style.display = 'none';
</script> `to the top of the "securedfile.php" so it will hide the form. Is workiking. Thakyou!!

Comment: No problem. And you gotta accept the answer with the green tick, so the topic is closed/answered.